# What does this statement mean "We highly recommend custom validation styles as native browser defaults are not announced to screen readers"?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-4, screen-readers

On Bootstrap 4's website for [Form Validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation) they state

> We highly recommend custom validation styles as native browser defaults are not announced to screen readers.

What does this mean? Do they recommend you use the native browser form validation? or to implement custom validation?

Comment: As far as I understand, it means that you should call `form.checkValidity()` explicitly instead of relying on default HTML5 validations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they mean is best explained with an example.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="32">
```

Note the maxlength.  Screenreaders will not be able to identify when one actually reaches that max length.

Therefore they are recommending that you use their `form.checkValidity()` and create a custom message to properly respond to users that are not able to recognize this problem. Typically this means creating a new element on the page with the `role="alert"`  the alert role informs the user that there is a message that *something* needs attention i.e. your message is too long

Edit: This applies to any conditions on your form.  So if certain characters aren't allowed, max & min lengths, etc.  Anything a user cannot do.

Source: https://www.w3.org/WAI/people-use-web/tools-techniques/ (Overview)